# Hide selected Features

Tags: openlayers-3

in ol3, after executing

layer.setVisible(false);

selected Features are still visible. I wanne all features of a layer to be completely hidden after I set the layer to be invisible. How to solve the problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: You got your answer. Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

First, clear the selection:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
var collection = select.getFeatures();
collection.clear();
```

or

```
select.getFeatures().clear();
```